# Is it possible to use oauth2 authorization with private shopify apps?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, shopify

As indicated, Private apps(http://wiki.shopify.com/Private_apps) section, only curl example is given. Is it possible to use oauth2 authorization with private apps? How can I use oauth2 authorization with shopify if it is not possible to use private apps with oauth2 authorization?

Answer (score 4):

The password that you're given with your private app will work as the access token if you set it as the `X-Shopify-Access-Token` header on your requests.

Comment: Thanks for response, But then what is the purpose of api key and shared secret of private app? I couldn't get temp_token with api key which is indicated at private app via oauth2 authorization. For private apps only http basic authentication works as I seen.